# CSS3 grayscale filter looks different on different images

Tags: css, grayscale

I have 3 icons of FCB, twitter and RSS and I want them to be grayscale but on hover they should change to color version. It is working great but these 3 images looks a bit different in grayscale. Is there a way to make them looks the same?
This is my code for grayscale:

```
img.grayscale{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

RSS and twitter looks almost the same but FCB icon is a lot darker. I think that the only way is to play with grayscale percentage. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle demo with the actual icons you are using?

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/UfVA3/

Comment: I see now... Are you sure that's the official Facebook blue? Looks a bit darker to me. But anyway, the greyscale works as it should, darker colours should be darker shades of grey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class of fb on the fb image and set

```
img.fb {
     opacity: 0.7;   
}
```

This will give the illusion of making the image more light.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pete_D/UfVA3/1/)

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I said it will give the illusion of making it. But its something you can use until you find a better solution.